# Python How to break loop with 0

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I don't understand why is not working on my code

```
def random_calculation(num):
    return((num*77 + (90+2-9+3)))


while random_calculation:
    num = int(input("Pleace enter number: "))
    if num == "0":
        break
    else:
        print(random_calculation(num))
```

Can you guide me what is wrong here, i really dont understand

Comment: `0` is an integer, `"0"` is a string. These are different things.

Comment: Because `num` can never be "0" since it's an integer. You may want `if num == 0` instead.

Comment: your problem is in  `while random_calculation:` use `while True:` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

You cannot do `while random_calculation` like this. You need to call the function, but since inside the loop you are already checking for a break condition, use while True instead.

Also, you are converting the input to int, but then comparing agains the string "0" instead of the int 0

Here's the corrected code:

```
def random_calculation(num):
    # 90+2-9+3 is a bit strange, but not incorrect.
    return((num*77 + (90+2-9+3)))


while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter number: "))
    if num == 0:
        break
    
    # you don't need an else, since the conditional would 
    # break if triggered, so you can save an indentation level
    print(random_calculation(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

so,when you start the loop it ask you what number you want to enter and then the code checks if the number is == to 0. IF the number is equal to 0: break the loop. IF the number is equal to any other number it prints the "random_calculation" function